# d3 Bar Chart not showing up or giving me any errors to work from

Tags: json, d3.js

Ok, so I'm trying to make a d3 chart, but when I do nothing shows up.  Here is how my data is coming out in the JSON:

```
[{"Commodity":"Base","num_complete_print":"3","num_incomplete_print":15},{"Commodity":"Blade","num_complete_print":"1","num_incomplete_print":53},{"Commodity":"DTE","num_complete_print":"1","num_incomplete_print":17},{"Commodity":"HUB","num_complete_print":"0","num_incomplete_print":"18"},{"Commodity":"MH","num_complete_print":"0","num_incomplete_print":"18"},{"Commodity":"Mid","num_complete_print":"0","num_incomplete_print":18},{"Commodity":"Top","num_complete_print":"0","num_incomplete_print":18}]
```

Here is my javascript....

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 100},
        width = 750 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width-100], .1); //width-100 to make room for the legend.

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        //.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
        //.range(["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e","d62728"]); //blue, orange, red
        //color code for Progress Report
        .range(["#00FFFF","#00FF00","#990099","#FF0000","#FFFF00"]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

    var svg = d3.select("#area_progress_report").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


        // Get the data
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($dataset_progress001); ?>;

    //d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
      color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Commodity"; }));

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        var y0 = 0;
        d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
        d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
      });

      //use this to sort the bars from largest to smallest
      //data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });

      x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Commodity; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis)
          .selectAll("text")  //added this line through rotate to change orientation of x axis
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", "-1em")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-90)" 
                });

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end");
        //  .text("Population");

      var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "g")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.Commodity) + ",0)"; });

      state.selectAll("rect")
          .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

      var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
          .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "legend")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

      legend.append("rect")
          .attr("x", width - 18)
          .attr("width", 18)
          .attr("height", 18)
          .style("fill", color);

      legend.append("text")
          .attr("x", width - 24)
          .attr("y", 9)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text(function(d) { return d; });

    //Added y label 10/28
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y label")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("y", -60)
        .attr("x",-190)
        .attr("dy", ".75em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .text("Number Of Components");
</script>
```

And of course in my body I have this

```
<div id="area_progress_report"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?  I include the d3 locally...

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <!-- added to try to avoid the d3 is not valid -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="d3-master/d3.v3.js"></script>   <!-- load the d3.js library -->     

            <script type="text/javascript" src="d3-master/d3.v3.min.js"></script>   <!-- load the d3.js library -->
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/wqHqP/

I simply replaced the line:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($dataset_progress001); ?>;
```

with your output JSON.

Comment: When I add <!DOCTYPE html> to the header of the page it works fine.  The problem I am facing now is I put my PHP to populate $dataset_progress001 in a function that is getting called on the page above where the script is.  If I add the data manually as you said it works....if I alert(data) it is returning null.

Comment: It was because I had a PHP function that was calculating the array to be json_encode.  When I took it out of a function and just applied to the page it works... Must have been the order of execution.

Comment: Yes, it seems like it must have been order of execution or how the variables were scoped. I wanted to first make sure all if the d3 setup code was correct, which it was, to rule it out as being a possible problem. Glad it works now!